# getElementById issue - drumpad

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-table, getelementbyid

I'm developing a web drum-Pad app. But I'm having problems with the getElementById statement when I want to change the class of the td. What I want to do is to highlight the td's when I click over them but it doesn't work.

It's strange because if I assign the id to a tr instead of assigning it to the td, the whole row of td highlight.

For example if I give to the nested table's first tr the id "KickButton" the class changes properly and the whole td row highlights when I click on the the first td of that tr.

I hope I explained properly my issue

Thanks in advance!

This is the HTML

```
<body onKeyPress = "keys()">
    <div class = "mainBox">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div id = "div2" class = "drumPadBox">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td onclick = "playKick()" id = "KickButton"> </td>
                        <td onclick = "playSnare()" id = "SnareButton"/>
                        <td onclick = "playHat()" id = "HatButton"> </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td> </td>
                        <td> </td>
                        <td> </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td> </td>
                        <td> </td>
                        <td> </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td> </td>
                        <td> </td>
                        <td> </td>
                    </tr>       
                </table>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </div>
</body>
```

This the CSS

```
<style>

    body{
        background:black;       
    }

    .mainBox{
    }

    .mainBox table{
        width: 50%;
        height: 90%;
        text-align: center;
        margin-left:auto; 
        margin-right:auto;
    }

    .mainBox tr{
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        text-align: center;
        margin-left:auto; 
        margin-right:auto;
    }

    .mainBox td{
        width: %;
        height: 100%;
        text-align: center;
        margin-left:auto; 
        margin-right:auto;
        background:black;
    }

    .drumPadBox table{
        width: 550px;
        height: 550px;
        margin:auto; 
        border-spacing: 0.2em

    }

    .drumPadBox tr{
        width: 300px;
        height: 100px;
        margin:auto; 
    }

    .drumPadBox td{
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        margin: auto;
        background: rgba(255,233,87,1);
        background: -moz-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, rgba(255,233,87,1) 0%, rgba(255,238,56,1) 22%, rgba(253,227,60,1) 31%, rgba(250,213,65,1) 43%, rgba(249,202,54,1) 49%, rgba(245,147,0,1) 78%, rgba(245,147,0,1) 83%);
        background: -webkit-gradient(radial, center center, 0px, center center, 100%, , color-stop(0%, rgba(255,233,87,1)), color-stop(22%, rgba(255,238,56,1)), color-stop(31%, rgba(253,227,60,1)), color-stop(43%, rgba(250,213,65,1)), color-stop(49%, rgba(249,202,54,1)), color-stop(78%, rgba(245,147,0,1)), color-stop(83%, rgba(245,147,0,1)));
        background: -webkit-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, rgba(255,233,87,1) 0%, rgba(255,238,56,1) 22%, rgba(253,227,60,1) 31%, rgba(250,213,65,1) 43%, rgba(249,202,54,1) 49%, rgba(245,147,0,1) 78%, rgba(245,147,0,1) 83%);
        background: -o-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, rgba(255,233,87,1) 0%, rgba(255,238,56,1) 22%, rgba(253,227,60,1) 31%, rgba(250,213,65,1) 43%, rgba(249,202,54,1) 49%, rgba(245,147,0,1) 78%, rgba(245,147,0,1) 83%);
        background: -ms-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, rgba(255,233,87,1) 0%, rgba(255,238,56,1) 22%, rgba(253,227,60,1) 31%, rgba(250,213,65,1) 43%, rgba(249,202,54,1) 49%, rgba(245,147,0,1) 78%, rgba(245,147,0,1) 83%);
        background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center, rgba(255,233,87,1) 0%, rgba(255,238,56,1) 22%, rgba(253,227,60,1) 31%, rgba(250,213,65,1) 43%, rgba(249,202,54,1) 49%, rgba(245,147,0,1) 78%, rgba(245,147,0,1) 83%);
        filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffe957', endColorstr='#f59300', GradientType=1 );
        border-style:none;
        border-width:1px;
        border-color: black;
        border-collapse:collapse;
        -webkit-border-radius: 1px;
        -moz-border-radius: 1px;
        border-radius: 1px;
        color: black;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px -2px rgba(255,203,71,1);
        -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px -2px rgba(255,203,71,1);
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px -2px rgba(255,203,71,1);
    }

    .activated{

    }

    .activated table{
        width: 550px;
        height: 550px;
        margin:auto; 
        border-spacing: 0.2em

    }

    .activated tr{
        width: 300px;
        height: 100px;
        margin:auto; 
    }

    .activated td{
        background: rgba(255,219,76,1);
        background: -moz-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, rgba(255,219,76,1) 12%, rgba(255,222,78,1) 17%, rgba(255,233,87,1) 38%, rgba(255,236,70,1) 49%, rgba(255,238,56,1) 58%, rgba(251,220,62,1) 78%, rgba(251,216,64,1) 83%, rgba(250,213,65,1) 86%);
        background: -webkit-gradient(radial, center center, 0px, center center, 100%, , color-stop(12%, rgba(255,219,76,1)), color-stop(17%, rgba(255,222,78,1)), color-stop(38%, rgba(255,233,87,1)), color-stop(49%, rgba(255,236,70,1)), color-stop(58%, rgba(255,238,56,1)), color-stop(78%, rgba(251,220,62,1)), color-stop(83%, rgba(251,216,64,1)), color-stop(86%, rgba(250,213,65,1)));
        background: -webkit-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, rgba(255,219,76,1) 12%, rgba(255,222,78,1) 17%, rgba(255,233,87,1) 38%, rgba(255,236,70,1) 49%, rgba(255,238,56,1) 58%, rgba(251,220,62,1) 78%, rgba(251,216,64,1) 83%, rgba(250,213,65,1) 86%);
        background: -o-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, rgba(255,219,76,1) 12%, rgba(255,222,78,1) 17%, rgba(255,233,87,1) 38%, rgba(255,236,70,1) 49%, rgba(255,238,56,1) 58%, rgba(251,220,62,1) 78%, rgba(251,216,64,1) 83%, rgba(250,213,65,1) 86%);
        background: -ms-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, rgba(255,219,76,1) 12%, rgba(255,222,78,1) 17%, rgba(255,233,87,1) 38%, rgba(255,236,70,1) 49%, rgba(255,238,56,1) 58%, rgba(251,220,62,1) 78%, rgba(251,216,64,1) 83%, rgba(250,213,65,1) 86%);
        background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center, rgba(255,219,76,1) 12%, rgba(255,222,78,1) 17%, rgba(255,233,87,1) 38%, rgba(255,236,70,1) 49%, rgba(255,238,56,1) 58%, rgba(251,220,62,1) 78%, rgba(251,216,64,1) 83%, rgba(250,213,65,1) 86%);
        filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffdb4c', endColorstr='#fad541', GradientType=1 );
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        margin: auto;
        opacity: 1;
        border-style:none;
        border-width:3px;
        border-color: black;
        border-collapse:collapse;
        -webkit-border-radius: 1px;
        -moz-border-radius: 1px;
        border-radius: 1px;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px 0px rgba(255,203,71,1);
        -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px 0px rgba(255,203,71,1);
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px 0px rgba(255,203,71,1);
    }

    </style>
```

This is the JS

```
<Script type= text/javascript>

    var cont = 1;

    function keys (){
        if (event.keyCode == 55){
            playKick();
        }else if (event.keyCode == 56){
            playSnare();
        }else if (event.keyCode == 57){
            playHat();
        }
    }


    function playKick() {
        document.getElementById('KickButton').className = "activated";
        setTimeout(function() {document.getElementById('KickButton').className ="drumPadBox";},100);
    }

    function playSnare() {
        document.getElementById('SnareButton').className ="activated";
        setTimeout(function() {document.getElementById('SnareButton').className ="drumPadBox";},100);
    }

    function playHat() {
        document.getElementById('HatButton').className ="activated";
        setTimeout(function() {document.getElementById('HatButton').className ="drumPadBox";},100);
    }


</script>
```

Comment: Try jquery. http://api.jquery.com/addclass/

Comment: Put your code in Jsfiddle & share
http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: This problem has nothing to do with `getElementById`. Your CSS rules simply don’t affect a `td` element with the class `activated`.